# Why to use Route Resolver if I can control DOM content using structural directives?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am learning the use of Angular Route Resolvers, and from some sources on web, I get idea that those are used to perform actions after the navigation event and before our component is loaded.

But, if I can control the loading of DOM using structural directives like `*ngIf` and perform required actions in `ngOnInit()` before loading of DOM, then what is the use case of resolvers.

Are they efficient and performance optimizers? **Is there specific case where I have no option other than using resolvers?**

(I am referring to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-resolvers as an example).

Comment: thought experiment: where exactly would you put that `*ngIf` which would replace resolver?

Comment: I guess that route resolvers actions are executed even before the ngOnInit lifecycle hook, in that case, you don't even have to worry about the existance of data

Comment: You are right, those are executed before `*ngOnInIt()`, but I can hold my DOM content using `*ngIf`, so why to have that latency using resolver?

Comment: You can see in the stackblitz example, there's no need for extra *ngIfs, that sometimes become fastidious if you have a lot of data to prefetch. in the example you have this: `    <span *ngIf="!users.length">You'll never see this span</span>
 `

Comment: But, I could show a loader in my target component at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvers can be useful for many reasons:

- the page content and the URL doesn't change until the data is loaded. So it the loading fails, the user isn't in front of a blank page, and can click the link again to retry.
- it makes the template easier to write, since you don't have to deal with data not being loaded yet, or being partially loaded
- it makes the code of the component simpler, since the component just needs to display data provided by the resolver, rather than loading it by itself (and reloading if the parameters change).
- if used consistently, resolvers allow using router events to display some generic loading indicator, whereas if each component loads its own data, you can centralize this code in a single place
- the resolver can be shared between several routes that need the same data

Their downsides is that

- it's yet another service to write, which dilutes the code of a component in one or several more additional places
- it can give a feeling of slowness, because nothing changes on the page until the data is loaded

Comment: As they allow us to write simplified and clean templates, so should they be overused?

Comment: It depends on how important the downsides are compared to the advantages. Like with basically everything.

Comment: When user clicks the link, nothing happens till observable is returned, so isn't that a bad usability experience? Also, as you said that URL doesn't gets changed until route gets resolved, so how we can show loader to fix 'nothing is happening' like feeling?

Comment: *isn't that a bad usability experience?*: it can be, which is the reason why my answer lists "it can give a feeling of slowness, because nothing changes on the page until the data is loaded" as a downside. Nothing is happening... unless you display an indicator that something is being loaded in the background. Just like you click on a link in any traditional web page, and the browser doesn't do anything other than displaying a loading animation in the tab header.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet. One last question: When resolver fails, so literally nothing happens, so what will be the good way to know a user that something has went wrong. If we weren't using resolver, we could at least show a message in target component's `Else` part of the DOM.

Comment: @GeniusGo no. The else part of the dom would be displayed while the data is being loaded. The user would just wonder why it keeps being displayed forever. The way to handle errors is the same in both cases: display some message somewhere when an error happens. That's typically done using an http interceptor.

Comment: Ok. Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find the resolver useful in these 2 cases:

1. When we enable page animations, like sliding pages to the left/right in the router outlet. The animation is smoother as the component gets loaded only after the data is resolved.
2. When data needs to be shared across child route components (it can be achieved just using services though).

For everything else I use *ngIf